# Convert golang protobuf enum from int32 to string

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am facing with the problem that protobuf I defined enum but its value is int32
Now I want someway or somehow to change all the protobuf defined to string
Or any code-hack for doing it in gateway without changing the protobuf.

Enum defined

```
  enum TimeUnit {
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 1;
  hours = 2;
  days = 3;
  months = 4;
}
message CacheDuration {
  uint32 Value = 1;
  TimeUnit Units = 2;
}
```

What i got from generated code now is
[image]
And it is the return value for front end to use. So they would see the value of Units = int32 like this:
[image]
The services communicate by generated struct protobuf.
I want to make it change to

`"Units":"days"`

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information around the setup and constraints you're operating with. grpc-gateway with the default marshaller in place will render enum values as strings, so it's unclear what issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String` method in your go code:

```
generatedTimeUnitEnum.String() // output: days
```

Comment: I know that method but the problem when generated protobuf it is int32 underlying... How to change it to string?